# [JS]Array merging without using array functions

Tags: javascript

I need help merging two arrays without using any of the array built in functions ( no concat, push, pop, shift, replace, sort, splice, etc)

And I've got to this point but I'm stuck.

```
function addTwoArrays(arr1, arr2){
    var merge = [], p;
    for(p = 0; p < arr1.length; p++){
        merge[arr1[p]] = true;
    }
    for(p = 0; p < arr2.length; p++){
        merge[arr2[p]] = true;
    }
    return Object.keys(merge);
}
window.alert(addTwoArrays([1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]));
```

return is 1,2,3,4 - instead of 1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1

Comment: `merge` is not an object

Comment: Do you mind if your solution involves making a string from arr1 and arr2 and then adds the two strings?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Array functions?

Comment: if it were up to me I'd use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to loop once - simply take arr1.length as a start index and add to the array:

```js
function addTwoArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  let start = arr1.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    arr1[start++] = arr2[i];
  }
  return arr1;
}

console.log(addTwoArrays([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1]));
```

Comment: issue with this approach is that merging will modify first array in-place.

Comment: @lazyvab: OP seems to "_need help merging"_, so how is that an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Keys are unique in a JSON object. So, Object.keys() will return unique occurrences of each element.
Instead try this:

```
function addTwoArrays(arr1, arr2){
    var merge = [], p, index = 0;
    for(p = 0; p < arr1.length; p++){
        merge[index++] = arr1[p];
    }
    for(p = 0; p < arr2.length; p++){
        merge[index++] = arr2[p];
    }
    return merge;
}
window.alert(addTwoArrays([1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mergedArray(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {
    let newArr = arrayOne
    let x = arrayOne.length
    let y = arrayTwo.length
    let z = arrayOne.length + arrayTwo.length
    let i, j

    for (i = x, j = 0; i < z && j < y; i++, j++) {
        newArr[i] = arrayTwo[j]
    }
    return newArr
}
```

Comment: Please include a code explanation in your answer.